# macOS Blue icons

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, icons

I'm using Storyboard's to develop a macOS Big Sur application, when I noticed that apps such as Xcode and App Store used nice little blue icons:

[image: App Store]
[image: XCode]

I could not find these in Xcode's interface builder anywhere. Does anybody know how to get those icons? (More specifically Xcode's blue plus button, next to "Create a new Xcode project")

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/sf-symbols/

Comment: @Tyler I tried it out, but all the icons are the regular gray color

Comment: I think the property you wish to set is called `tintColor`.

Comment: Glad to help. (1) I'm *not* macOS*, so YMMV. (2) The icons, even gray, *are* SF-Symbols. (3) Since most apps use a navigation bar, look into using `.setTitleTextAttributes` for setting foreground color. And finally, (4) be sure to check out light/dark mode - which exists in both iOS and macOS. Again, glad to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is `plus.app` in the system icon

[image]